# How to implement in app purchase in ionic 3

Tags: android, ios, ionic-framework, ionic3, in-app-purchase

I am curios to implement in app purchase but there for i have some questions. I have already seen [this post](https://medium.com/@andrew.thielcole/in-app-purchases-with-ionic-3-af13b21f49f2) that helped to setup google account and products. I have created two subscriptions on google app purchase which is monthly and yearly with 7 day free trial also. Please see below my doubts and questions.

1. It seems i can get only one product at time with in app purchase 2 [plugin](https://ionicframework.com/docs/native/in-app-purchase-2/)
2. I need to show subscription list manually and click on each subscription will get product details ?
3. After purchase we need to store current subscription details on server side to maintain user current subscription ?
4. When auto renewal happen then do i need to register web-hook in google/apple developer account to notify our server so we can extend expiry date ? and with out web-hook is possible then how can achieve that and what can be pros and cons ?
5. What is basic idea to implement restore purchases if user login on second mobile with same google/apple account ?

Thanks,
Your help will be appreciated.